# Magento 2, Group the options of an attribute in layered navigation frontend

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Magento 2, How can I group the attributes in layered navigation frontend?

For Example:

**GROUP NAME 1**

-> Filter one

-> Filter two

-> Filter three

**GROUPNAME 2**

-> Filter one

-> Filter two

-> Filter three